# Suitable native AWS solution for fast growing long lived indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

My requirements are,
1. Fast growing long lived indexes.
2. TPM - 33k. Potentially go up to 48k.
3. Per year 2B indexes.
4. Non key attribute will be updated ~120 times.

I'm checking all options - DynamoDB, AWS Elastic Search, Cloudwatch etc. Can you please guide me preferable solution considering cost, availability and maintenance (hot partition and higher provisioned throughput and increasing cost of Dynamo Db) aspects?

Answer (score 0):

As I have worked on ElasticSearch, I would recommend you the same.

**Yes, it will support the matrix you mentioned**.

**It is horizontally scalable.**

Check out the [Case studies of various companies](https://www.elastic.co/use-cases) using elasticsearch for their needs. 
In these case studies, focus on the matrices [they](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/tour/2017/los-angeles/revolutionizing-the-fan-experience-with-search-at-ticketmaster) had and what sort of Elasticsearch infra they have used.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to know "why not DynamoDB"  aspect.